# Can not enable text field dynamically using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue.I need to enable my text field dynamically using angular.js but its not happening. I am explaining my code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="gl in galleryDatas">
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="clickedRow(gl.checked,$index)" name="" ng-model="gl.checked"> {{$index+1}}</td>
<td><img ng-src="upload/{{gl.image}}" border="0" name="image" style="width:100px; height:100px;" /></td>
<td><textarea id="address" name="desc" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add comment" rows="6" ng-model="gl.description" style="height:70px" ng-readonly="gl.galComnt"></textarea></td>
<td>
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Edit" ng-click="editComment(gl.gallery_id,$index,gl.description)"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw"></i>{{gl.galEDit}}</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
$http({
                method:'POST',
                url:"php/customerInfo.php",
                data:imageData,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).then(function successCallback(response){
                $scope.formDiv=false;
                $scope.gallery=true;
                $scope.galleryDatas=[];
                for(var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
                    var data={'gallery_id':response.data[i].    gallery_id,'subcat_id':response.data[i].subcat_id,'image':response.data[i].image,'description':response.data[i].description,'galComnt':true,'galEDit':"Edit"};
                    $scope.galleryDatas.push(data);
                }
            }
```

Here i need while user will click on edit button the respective row description field will be editable. My code is given below.

```
$scope.editComment=function(galid,index,comnt){
        if($scope.galleryDatas[index].galEDit=="Edit"){
            $scope.galleryDatas[index].galEDit="Update";
            $scope.galleryDatas[index].galComnt=false;
        }
}
```

But here its not working. Here i need while user will click on any row edit button,the respective row text area will be editable.Please help me.

Comment: You may got another error otherwise your code should be working :) . see the console log

Comment: i am not getting any error in console.

Comment: I have checked your code with demo data in plunker. that was working correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should not be playing with `index` that will end up with mess(even more when you use more filters on `ng-repeat`), instead just pass an `gl` object to `editComment` function. Whatever you change in the object will reflect to it original reference and on view as well.

```
ng-click="editComment(gl)"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.editComment=function(gl){
    if(gl.galEDit=="Edit"){
        gl.galEDit="Update";
        gl.galComnt=false;
    }
}
```

Follow the same thing for `clickedRow` function.

Comment: Have you changed same for other function clickedRow

Comment: `clickedRow` function called for check the check box. But here i dont need to check any check box initially.